# How can i implement key management service for mvc4 application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, encryption

Our application send sensitive information to clients(each client has its own sensitive information).Not all the information will be sensitive but only few fields will be sensitive so whenever client request data, we want to encrypt that information and send it across.To the client ends, they will have their key management system(different client can have different key management services.) so now what we want to achieve is that when client receive this information then our response( probably in JSON) will ask them to provide key from the technique they are using and using this key they will decrypt the response.And also, whenever client update their information then we want to store it in encrypted form in our database.This seems to be bit complicated but it will be really helplful if anyone can suggest some solution for it.

Comment: Why not just use SSL?

Comment: do we have any other way to do the same except the SSL. we are looking for something else.Also, not sure whether SSL will work with our scenario or not.